# items not showing in cart in pinia state in vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

my cart items is not showing in the cart(which is in state using pinia) after adding them using an action from a button in the shop page

my code:

store.js(using pinia)

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import Products from "../db.json";

export const useCounterStore = defineStore("counter", {
  state: () => ({
    cart: [],
  }),
  actions: {
    addToCart(id) {
      this.cart.push(id)
      console.log("test passed!")
    }
  }
});
```

shop.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="shop">
    <h1>shop</h1>
    <div class="products" v-for="item in Products" :key="item.id">
      {{ item.name }} {{ item.price }}$
      <button @click="storeCounter.addToCart(item.id)">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import { useCounterStore } from '../stores/counter';
import Products from "../db.json"

const storeCounter = useCounterStore()

</script>
```

cart.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="cart">
        <h1>cart</h1>
        <div class="cartitems" v-for="item in storeCounter.cart" :key="item.id">{{ item.name }} {{ item.price }}</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useCounterStore } from '../stores/counter';
import Products from "../db.json"

const storeCounter = useCounterStore()

</script>
```

why it is not working for me? i assume i did everything right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shop.vue` is only pushing the id number into the store's `cart` array

```html
<button @click="storeCounter.addToCart(item.id)">
```

`cart.vue` is attempting to display the `cart` array as if contains full product objects and not just the ids

```html
<div class="cartitems" v-for="item in storeCounter.cart" :key="item.id">
  {{ item.name }} {{ item.price }}
</div>
```

This can be easily fixed by changing `shop.vue` to add the full `item` instead of just `item.id`

```html
<button @click="storeCounter.addToCart(item)">
```